# How to remove *some* items from array when there is repetition? (Lodash/Underscore preferred)

Tags: javascript, node.js, underscore.js, lodash

I'm trying to write a function that filters out triplets from an array of 6 dice. Is there an easy way to do it using Lodash or Underscore?

```js
noTriplets([1,1,1,3,3,5]) // = [3,3,5]
noTriplets([1,1,1,1,3,5]) // = [1,3,5]
noTriplets([1,1,1,1,1,5]) // = [1,1,5]
noTriplets([1,1,1,5,5,5]) // = []
noTriplets([1,1,1,1,1,1]) // = []
```

Comment: That depends on what you consider easy ... What've you done so far?

Comment: Hey Joe - can you confirm what condition you're looking for? In example 3, you return two `1`s in your array, but in example 4 and 5, you return none. The condition is that each time there is three of a number, remove those three, but if there is four, you want to return 1. If there is 6, you want to return none because you remove 3 and 3. Is this right?

Comment: @ChristopherMesser You're correct. I want to remove any triplets in the array.

Comment: @Teemu See my answer below. It looks a little dirty to me, since it mutates the original array. A temporary variable would do the trick, I guess, but I don't like having to create the triplet as a separate array, then iterating through it.

Answer (score 2):

It's a little rough and dirty, but it doesn't require you to know your triplets ahead of time. Within the `noTriplets()` - I create a quick hashMap and then loop through that object. The loop logic handles the triplet piece.

```js
const arrayTestOne = [1,1,1,3,3,5];
const arrayTestTwo = [1,1,1,1,3,3,5];
const arrayTestThree = [1,1,1,3,3,3];
const arrayTestFour = [1,1,1,1,3,3,3,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,7,7];

const hashMap = (array) => array.reduce((allNums, num) => {
  if (num in allNums) {
    allNums[num]++
  }
  else {
 allNums[num] = 1
  }
  return allNums
}, {})

function noTriplets(arr) {
  let newArr = [];
  let obj = hashMap(arr);
  for (var key in obj) {
    for (let i=0; i < obj[key] % 3; i++) {
      newArr.push(key)
    }
  }
  console.log(newArr)
}

noTriplets(arrayTestOne)
noTriplets(arrayTestTwo)
noTriplets(arrayTestThree)
noTriplets(arrayTestFour)
```

Comment: This is the method I was looking for, except the implementation can be made a lot shorter using lodash. Here's my take on it: `function noTriplets(arr) {
  var hashMap = _.countBy(arr);
  return _.flatten(_.keys(hashMap).map(n => Array(hashMap[n]%3).fill(n)))
}`

Answer (score 1):

You could use a count for every item and calculate how many items to ignore.

```js
function noTriplets(array) {
    var hash = {};

    array.forEach(function (a) {
        hash[a] = hash[a] || { count: 0 };
        hash[a].ignore = Math.floor(++hash[a].count / 3) * 3;
    });

    return array.filter(function (a, i) {
        return --hash[a].ignore < 0;
    });
}

console.log(noTriplets([1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 5])); // [3, 3, 5]
console.log(noTriplets([1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 5])); // [1, 3, 5]
console.log(noTriplets([1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 5])); // [1, 1, 5]
console.log(noTriplets([1, 1, 1, 5, 5, 5])); // []
console.log(noTriplets([1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1])); // []
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use an object to record the values and then generate a new array using the previous object.

```js
function noTriplets(arr){
  var tripletCount = arr.reduce((dice,value) => {
    dice[value] = dice[value] || { count : 0 };
    dice[value].count = (dice[value].count + 1) % 3;
    return dice;
  },{});
  
  return Object.keys(tripletCount).reduce((arr,key) => {
    return arr.concat(new Array(tripletCount[key].count).fill(key));
  },[]);
}

console.log(noTriplets([1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 5])); // [3, 3, 5]
console.log(noTriplets([1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 5])); // [1, 3, 5]
console.log(noTriplets([1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 5])); // [1, 1, 5]
console.log(noTriplets([1, 1, 1, 5, 5, 5])); // []
console.log(noTriplets([1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1])); // []
```

Answer (score 1):

My universal solution with pure JS. You can specify how many repetition items should be removed. For example, here created `noDoubles`, `noTriplets` and `noQuadruples` methods.

```js
function isArrayWithIdenticalElements(array) {
  return array.length > 1 && !!array.reduce(function(a, b){ return (a === b) ? a : NaN; });
}

function noRepetition(numberOfRepetition, array) {
  var sliceLength = numberOfRepetition - 1;
  var pointer = sliceLength;
  var element = array[pointer];

  while (element) {
    if (isArrayWithIdenticalElements(array.slice(pointer - sliceLength, pointer + 1))) {
      array.splice(pointer - sliceLength, numberOfRepetition);

      pointer = pointer - sliceLength;
      element = array[pointer];
    } else {
      pointer = pointer + 1;
      element = array[pointer];
    }
  }

  return array;
}

var noDoubles = noRepetition.bind(null, 2);
var noTriplets = noRepetition.bind(null, 3);
var noQuadruples = noRepetition.bind(null, 4);

console.log('noTriplets([1,1,1,3,3,5] ==> ', noTriplets([1,1,1,3,3,5])); // = [3,3,5]
console.log('noTriplets([1,1,1,1,3,5] ==> ', noTriplets([1,1,1,1,3,5])); // = [1,3,5]
console.log('noTriplets([1,1,1,1,1,5] ==> ', noTriplets([1,1,1,1,1,5])); // = [1,1,5]
console.log('noTriplets([1,1,1,5,5,5] ==> ', noTriplets([1,1,1,5,5,5])); // = []
console.log('noTriplets([1,1,1,1,1,1] ==> ', noTriplets([1,1,1,1,1,1])); // = []

console.log('noQuadruples([1,1,1,3,3,5] ==> ', noQuadruples([1,1,1,3,3,5])); // = [1,1,1,3,3,5]
console.log('noQuadruples([1,1,1,1,3,5] ==> ', noQuadruples([1,1,1,1,3,5])); // = [3,5]

console.log('noDoubles([1,1,1,5,5,5] ==> ', noDoubles([1,1,1,5,5,5])); // = [1,5]
```

Answer (score 0):

Great answers! After reading everyone's answers, especially Christopher Messer's, I came up with a lodash-based version:

```js
function noTriplets(arr) {
  var hashMap = _.countBy(arr)
  var filler = n => Array(hashMap[n] % 3).fill(n)
  return _.flatten(_.keys(hashMap).map(filler))
}
```